# How to add p-values from prop.trend.test to gtsummary table

Tags: gtsummary

My goal is to show number of cases over time and its trend by group. Therefore I created a gtsummary table and performed a prop.trend.test.

Initially I created groups with mutate(). Then I selected my groups and case-year and created a table with number of cases per year divided by different groups.

Then I would like to add the p-values from prop.trend.test to the table, which unfortunately does not work, because this test is not included in gtsummary.

The add_p() gives the wrong p-values. The prop.trend.test looks like this: prop.trend.test(x = table(group$case-year), n = table(data$case-year))

One solution would be to create a customfunction but I do not know how to transform this specific test.

Or is there a way to manually add values in a new column?

I tried to create a tibble with the p-values of my groups. But then I have a problem inserting it with modify_table_body, because the tibble and the table are not equally sized.

```
The code looks like this: 

### generating random dataset

dataset <- data.frame(
  case_year = rep(1950:1959, each = 300/10),
  numbers = sample(1:300, 300, replace = TRUE)
)

### creating groups for prop.trend.test

numbers_0_100 <-  subset(dataset, numbers  <= 100)
numbers_101_200 <-  subset(dataset, numbers >= 101 & dataset$numbers <= 200)
numbers_201_300 <-  subset(dataset, numbers >= 201, )

### prop.trend.test

prop.trend.test(x = table(numbers_0_100$case_year), n = table(dataset$case_year))
prop.trend.test(x = table(numbers_101_200$case_year), n = table(dataset$case_year))
prop.trend.test(x = table(numbers_201_300$case_year), n = table(dataset$case_year))

### mutating data for gtsummary table

dataset2 <- dataset %>%
  mutate(numbers_0_100 = numbers <= 100,
         numbers_101_200 = numbers >= 101 & numbers <= 200,
         numbers_201_300 = numbers >= 201)


### creating the table

dataset2 %>% 
  select(case_year, numbers_0_100, numbers_101_200, numbers_201_300) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = case_year)
```

Comment: I think you'll have better luck with `add_stat()` over `modify_table_body(). If you update your post more a minimal reproducible example, we can be of more help. Ideally, you'll create a base gtsummary table and explain how you wish the p-value to be calculate given your data. Use an example data frame like mtcars or gtsummary::trial

Comment: Thanks for the code. Are you able to update the primary post with this code, and can you also update the code to use data that we can access as well? That could be some dummy data you create

Comment: I tried change the post, hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding a p-value, I would write a custom function that can be passed to `add_p()`.  You can review this article for details on the structure of the custom function. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html#custom-functions-1

```r
dataset <- 
  data.frame(
    case_year = rep(1950:1959, each = 300/10),
    numbers = sample(1:300, 300, replace = TRUE)
  ) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    numbers_0_100 = numbers <= 100,
    numbers_101_200 = numbers >= 101 & numbers <= 200,
    numbers_201_300 = numbers >= 201
  )


### write a function to do `prop.trend.test()`
calculate_prop_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  # subset to non-missing
  data <- tidyr::drop_na(data, dplyr::all_of(c(variable, by)))
  
  prop.trend.test(
    x = table(data[[variable]], data[[by]])[2, ], # get the second row (the positive row)
    n = table(data[[by]])
  ) |> 
    broom::tidy()
}

dataset |> 
  dplyr::select(case_year, numbers_0_100, numbers_101_200, numbers_201_300) |> 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = case_year) |> 
  gtsummary::add_p(test = ~calculate_prop_test) |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stack overflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **1950**, N = 30 | **1951**, N = 30 | **1952**, N = 30 | **1953**, N = 30 | **1954**, N = 30 | **1955**, N = 30 | **1956**, N = 30 | **1957**, N = 30 | **1958**, N = 30 | **1959**, N = 30 | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numbers_0_100 | 12 (40%) | 15 (50%) | 14 (47%) | 8 (27%) | 14 (47%) | 13 (43%) | 8 (27%) | 12 (40%) | 10 (33%) | 13 (43%) | 0.4 |
| numbers_101_200 | 8 (27%) | 8 (27%) | 7 (23%) | 11 (37%) | 9 (30%) | 7 (23%) | 13 (43%) | 7 (23%) | 12 (40%) | 10 (33%) | 0.3 |
| numbers_201_300 | 10 (33%) | 7 (23%) | 9 (30%) | 11 (37%) | 7 (23%) | 10 (33%) | 9 (30%) | 11 (37%) | 8 (27%) | 7 (23%) | 0.8 |

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>